# Elasticsearh match as many fields as possible

Tags: elasticsearch

Say we have the following attributes:

```
gender=male
location=US
network=Facebook
```

And I have the following data stored in Elasticsearch:

```
{ some_data: {}, attributes: ["US", "Facebook"] }
{ some_data: {}, attributes: ["Facebook"] }
{ some_data: {}, attributes: ["male", "AR", "LinkedIn"] }
{ some_data: {}, attributes: ["female", "US", "Facebook"] }
{ some_data: {}, attributes: ["male", "US", "LinkedIn"] }
{ some_data: {}, attributes: ["male", "US", "Facebook"] }
```

I want Elasticsearch to return all the following that match the "attributes" variable EXACTLY. Ex:

```
1) attributes: ["male", "US", "Facebook"] # All attributes match
2) attributes: ["male", "US"] # Two attributes combined match
3) attributes: ["male", "Facebook"] # Two attributes combined match
4) attributes: ["US", "Facebook"] # Two attributes combined match
5) attributes: ["male"] # Only one matches
6) attributes: ["US"] # Only one matches
7) attributes: ["Facebook"] # Only one matches
```

In this example, we would get:

```
1) { some_data: {}, attributes: ["male", "US", "Facebook"] } # All match
2) { some_data: {}, attributes: ["US", "Facebook"] } # Two matches
3) { some_data: {}, attributes: ["Facebook"] } # One match
```

Two things must be taken into consideration:

1) I don't want all fields that match gender='male'. I want only those results that match exactly a combination of the fields given at the beginning.
2) This algorithm must be available for n elements. In this example, I used 3 to simplify it all, but we might have 30 attributes to query.

For that reason, it would be nice to have only one query to database.

Comment: [This documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html#_equals_exactly) may be helpful. It explains why the kind of query you're describing is challenging and how to form it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html#_equals_exactly) I commented with earlier, it will be easiest for you to add a tag_count field and execute your query that way. To get your desired behavior, you want to specify `(male AND tag_count=1) OR (male AND facebook AND tag_count=2)`, which translates into 
`SHOULD [(MUST male and tag_count=1) (MUST male and facebook and tag_count=2)]` in the Elasticsearch DSL. (should is an OR and must is an AND).

For obvious reasons, this doesn't scale well with 30 tags, but maybe this will get you on the right track.

With the following data inserted into Elasticsearch:

```
{ "tags":["male"], "tag_count":1 }
{ "tags":["male","facebook"], "tag_count":2 }
{ "tags":["male","linkedin"], "tag_count":2 }
{ "tags":["male","US", "facebook"], "tag_count":3 }
{ "tags":["male","Germany", "facebook"], "tag_count":3 }
```

And this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tags": "male"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tag_count": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tags": "male"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tags": "facebook"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tag_count": 2
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following results:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "test_index",
      "_type" : "mult_query",
      "_id" : "AVegvUyzNutW6yNguPqZ",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "tags" : [ "male" ],
        "tag_count" : 1
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "test_index",
      "_type" : "mult_query",
      "_id" : "AVegvPSFNutW6yNguPqX",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "tags" : [ "male", "facebook" ],
        "tag_count" : 2
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```